# Remote Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a remote database from my machine using dbBeaver as database visualizer.  I can't seem to get it to connect and I think it is due to one or all of these reasons wrong connection type, access permissions, error with the port.  Below is my configuration (The names have been changed).  Any help is appreciated thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Assumption**: you know how to use the program, also it's working properly.

in your `cPanel`, you need to navigate to `Remote MySQL`[image]

and you need to put wildcard `%`(or you can use your IP address if you've static IP address locally.) in `textbox`. Click Add Host Button.

[image]

I'm using `SQLyoq`, and it's works perfect.

[image]

All you need to set `Remote Access`.

Comment: That seems like it is the issue. Thanks